# How to monitor time changes in iOS when the app is open?

Tags: ios, nsdate

Is there a way to actively check the time within the app when open? I would like to execute an action every day when the time changes to 10:00 PM.

When the app is first opened, I can check the time in `viewDidLoad`, but how do I check the time when the app is open?

Comment: when ever you need check the time with you own method or set the timer with repeat.

Comment: Do that in one of the application delegate functions